# How do I define that a resource is from datatype xsd.integer in RDF?

Tags: xsd, rdf, rdfs

is it possible in rdf to define/model that a resource with uri http://example.com/counter has the data type integer because it has integer values.

For example in Turtle:

```
ex:counter rdf:type xsd.integer.
ex:counter ex:value "3".
```

the first statement is wrong. possible would be "3" rdf:type xsd:integer. right? So how can I express that counter has only values from type integer. Is it possible with rdfs:Dataype or rdfs:range?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to say that `ex:counter` identifies an integer, then the triple `ex:counter rdf:type xsd:integer` is correct and sufficient, assuming you interpret the triple according to an entailment regime that recognises the datatype `xsd:integer`. If you want to say that `ex:counter` is specifically the integer 3, you'll need a more expressive regime. For instance, using `owl:sameAs`: `ex:counter owl:sameAs 3`.

Comment: do you have any reference for your claims?

Comment: RDF 1.1 Semantics is the reference. To be precise, you need to consider the RDFS entailment regime, recognising `xsd:integer`. In there, it is said (in Section 9) that the extension of a datatype *d* (i.e., the set of things that are of type *d*) is the value space of *d*. This entails that if *x* `rdf:type` *d*, then *x* is in the value space of *s*. In particular, if `ex:counter rdf:type xsd:integer`, then `ex:counter` is in the value space of `xsd:integer`, which is the set of integers.